# Jenkins tfs plug-in and checkout source on remote node

Tags: linux, jenkins, tfs, jenkins-plugins

First, I'm a Jenkins neophyte.  I have made a free-style software project in Jenkins to perform my Linux build.  The Jenkins server is running on Windows so there are slave nodes configured for doing this Linux build.  The sources are kept in a TFS server.

I updated our TFS plugin to the latest of 4.0.0.  This plugin says that it is no longer necessary for slave nodes to have the Team Explorer Everywhere package installed as it uses the Java API.  However, when I kick off my build, I get this:

```
Started by user Andy Falanga (afalanga)
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building remotely on dmdevlnx64-01 (PY27-64 CENTOS6-64 LOG4CPLUS PY26-64) in workspace /home/builder/jenkins/workspace/Linux Autotools Build

Deleting project workspace... done

Querying for remote changeset at '$/Sources/Branches/Andy/AutotoolsMigration' as of 'D2015-10-05T18:26:27Z'...
Query result is: Changeset #4872 by 'WINNTDOM\afalanga' on '2015-09-25T23:36:24Z'.
Listing workspaces from http://ets-tfs:8080/tfs/SoftwareCollection...
...  Long list of workspaces
Workspace Created by Team Build                                                      
Getting version 'C4872' to '/home/builder/jenkins/workspace/Linux Autotools Build'...
Finished getting version 'C4872'.
[Linux Autotools Build] $ /bin/bash /tmp/hudson7081873611439714406.sh
Bootstrapping autotools
/tmp/hudson7081873611439714406.sh: line 4: ./bootstrap: No such file or directory
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Notifying upstream projects of job completion
Finished: FAILURE
```

I log into that system and look in the directory `/home/builder/jenkins/workspace/Linux Autotools Build` and sure enough, there's nothing there.  My configuration is pretty simple.

- I have discard old builds checked and a simple rotation (this is just me learning how to use it).
- I have it set to "Restrict where the build is done" and a label which associates to the 3 slave nodes for doing this build.
- All TFS credentials are input and correct.
- No build triggers
- A simple shell script for **Build**->**Execute Shell** which bootstraps the autotools and calls configure and then make.

What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer and am posting it here in case someone runs into this.  This seems better than simply deleting the question.  The TFS plugin doesn't seem to like spaces in the project name.  The name before `Linux Autotools Build` which didn't work and the name now, `LinuxAutotoolsBuild` which does.

The errors provided by the Jenkins system didn't provide enough information for this to be apparent.  After trying a few other things the thought occurred, "Perhaps the spaces are causing grief."

Hope this helps someone.